# Need to resize Ubuntu root partition but cant use live boot usb

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, live-usb, root

I am running a Dell XPS 13 7390, dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04

Apparently when I first set it up I absent-mindedly allotted far too little space for my `/` dir, 10GB. Only 3 months in and I'm running out of space.

I can't resize the partition (AFAIK) form inside Ubuntu since it is mounted.

I can't seem to do so from Windows either. Windows Disk Manager only recognizes NTFS, not ext4. I am hesitant to trust third-party software, but I tried one called `DiskGenius` following [these instructions](https://www.eassos.com/blog/how-to-resize-ubuntu-partition-without-data-loss-in-ubuntu-windows/), and I got a message that there were partition errors that needed to be fixed first, and suggested that the entire disk was damaged... Hopefully not as it's a brand new computer, and both OS run just fine.

I can't seem to use a live USB either! Instead of booting from the USB, I get greeted with a "Preboot Check" for Windows, and all the BIOS settings I have played with (like turning off Secure Boot) make no difference here. For the briefest of moments before it goes into preboot check, I see the message:

```
Failed to open \EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi: Not Found
start.image() returned Not Found
```

Thus far all searches for that error message suggest making a live USB as a solution to fix a broken OS, not about fixing a (possibly?) broken live boot.

**ALL I WANT** is to resize my `/` directory to have 25 GB instead of 10. But I don't seem to have a way to do this that does not give me some error. I am not sure what the problem to get around is!

What is the best way to get unblocked here? Should I just start downloading a bunch of random 3rd-Party window programs until one of them works? That seems risky... Could the USB image have gotten damaged? It worked 3 months ago when I installed Ubuntu with it!

EDIT: Was able to use Live USB afterall - one for gParted and not all of Ubuntu, perhaps that one just got corrupted since I used it last somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a GParted live USB with Startup Disk Creator. The GParted live USB is about 1/10 the size of an Ubuntu live USB and it boots on anything.

1. [Download](https://gparted.org/download.php) the GParted Live iso file.
2. Run the built-in Startup Disk Creator application, and follow the instructions in the GUI to install GParted Live on your USB flash drive.

You can also create a GParted live USB from Windows by following the instructions from [GParted live on USB](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php).

If the GParted live USB fails to boot on your system I recommend that you take a serious look at your UEFI/BIOS settings.

Comment: That worked! I ended up using the terminal instructions to make the Live USB on the gParted website, but otherwise just as you said.

I suspect my live USB for ubuntu got damaged somehow? Odd considering that I used it to install ubuntu on this computer. Guess I'll need to make a new one.

Now have 25GB of space in `/` which I hope will last me a long while!