# Booting Gparted with GRUB

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

I'm trying to boot into Gparted with a USB stick I have, but when I turn the computer on, it brings me to the GRUB menu.  I have a dual boot Ubuntu/Windows computer and am trying to shrink the Windows partition and grow the Ubuntu partition.  I'm not great at this kind of stuff, and hoping for fairly clear instructions how to go about doing this.

I tried following [these similar instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947409/is-there-a-way-to-boot-from-usb-through-grub-menu), but I got stuck at the step "chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi".  I have a feeling that command isn't exactly the same for my situation, but not sure what else I'm supposed to put.  Otherwise though, the commands I entered showed good signs, like saying something like it being a gparted fat-formatted partition, or something like that.  But also not sure if that is the best route to go to boot gparted.

Also, I'm pretty sure my USB stick is properly formatted, I followed [these instructions](https://www.fosslinux.com/1068/how-to-create-a-gparted-live-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-derivatives.htm) to be specific.

Edit: [Suggested question/answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224930/need-to-resize-ubuntu-root-partition-but-cant-use-live-boot-usb) seems to be related to getting a bootable USB drive w/ GParted, but I have one already, and am having troubles with booting it

Comment: I'm able to get a GParted USB drive, but I think I'm having issues booting (when I turn the computer on w/ the USB plugged in, it brings me straight to GRUB).  It seems this answer gives clarity on how to make the USB stick w/ GParted though, is that so?

Comment: Try changing the boot priority in UEFI/BIOS so that the computer boots to the GParted live USB first: [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/q/208417/).

Comment: Yes, I followed those instructions and was able to get the USB to the boot screen!  I ran into another issue, but that is a separate issue than this.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: @user8243: Just reread your question. You should not be using GParted to shrink a Windows partition. The GParted site gives warnings about doing so. You should be using **Windows Disk Management**. Click "This PC" and select "Manage", then "Disk Management". Right click the volume you want to shrink and click "Shrink Volume".

Comment: @karel: What does this question have to do with boot priority? The OP wants to boot GParted using GRUB, a reasonable request. Obviously if he is dual bootin Ubuntu and Windows his computer already boots GRUB first. It's priority is fine. My answer, which is to the point, has no place on the confusing page you recommend. Anyway the question is actually about shrinking a Windows System disk. This should be done with Windows Disk Management, not GParted.

Comment: Windows 10 and GParted https://superuser.com/questions/1370229/unable-to-resize-system-partition-using-gparted

Answer (score 0):

### Add GParted menuentry to GRUB

If all else fails, put your GParted ISO in a folder named ISOs in the root directory and boot using GRUB2 and the following menuentry:

```
menuentry "GParted 64-bit ISO" {
  set root=(hd0,1)
  set isofile="/ISOs/gparted-live-1.1.0-5-amd64.iso"
  loopback loop $isofile
  linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live config union=overlay username=user components noswap noeject vga=788 ip= net.ifnames=0 toram=filesystem.squashfs findiso=$isofile
  initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

Confirm your root partition=(hd0,1) and the GParted version number.

Then copy the above menuentry to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom/` and run `sudo update-grub`.

Select `GParted 64-bit ISO` from your GRUB menu when booting.

Comment: You're able to do this from Ubuntu itself?

Comment: @user8243: I copied the menuentry from the internet, I will confirm it is still working.

Comment: @user8243 This revised menuentry works for me booting the GParted Live ISO from the hard drive. It should also work for booting from Live USB using GRUB2  bootloader. Just confirm location of root partition.