# How do I install Ubuntu on a laptop with eMMC?

Tags: system-installation, emmc

I have an ASUS laptop with an eMMC.

I can't format the drives in the installer menu.

I get a ext4 partition error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to resize Ubuntu root partition but cant use live boot usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224930/need-to-resize-ubuntu-root-partition-but-cant-use-live-boot-usb) or select the *Try Ubuntu* option from the Ubuntu live USB and run GParted from there.